# JHipster with @PreAuthorize always allow access

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

My Resource has this code:

```
    @DeleteMapping("/devices/{id}")
    @Timed
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteDevice(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete Device : {}", id);
        deviceService.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, id.toString())).build();
    }
```

It is supposed to be executed only by users with 'ROLE_ADMIN'. However, any logged user can run it, even if they don't possess the ROLE_ADMIN authority.

I've also tried by adding

```
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/api/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
```

on the SecurityConfiguration, but requests are never blocked. What am I missing? I'm using JHipster 6.9.1

Comment: Can you add your configuration as well e.g. is prePostEnabled enabled?

Comment: Indeed, this was missing. Post as answer so that I can accept it. It is weird however that this is not enabled by default and JHipster docs don't mention it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment - enable prePostEnabled in your `Configuration` as well to active the method security:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
  prePostEnabled = true, 
...)
```

Why it isnt't enabled by default by JHipster I don't know

Comment: Actually, the documentation is correct but this was a bug on JHipster part when using UAA